# How to override Model.delete() so that no cascade deletion ever happens for an instance?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cascading-deletes, django-2.2

I need to customize a [`Model.delete()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#deleting-objects) so that it doesn't perform any cascade deletes and instead raises an exception if there are any objects that reference the instance. It seems the default [implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L911) doesn't allow to skip the deletion of related objects:

```
def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
    using = using or router.db_for_write(self.__class__, instance=self)
    assert self.pk is not None, (
        "%s object can't be deleted because its %s attribute is set to None." %
        (self._meta.object_name, self._meta.pk.attname)
    )

    collector = Collector(using=using)
    collector.collect([self], keep_parents=keep_parents)
    return collector.delete()
```

How can I make sure Django doesn't cascade delete any related objects?

Comment: Isn't that `models.PROTECT` on the Foreign keys which reference the object being deleted? IIRC that  will raise `IntegrityError`.

Comment: @nigel222 Yes, but I also want to make sure no related objects will be deleted even if someone adds a model with a  'cascade' foreign key (e.g. by mistake, copy/paste etc)

Answer (score 2):

with your model use :

```
modelName = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='things')
```

also, note you have six types of operations are :

- **CASCADE**: When the referenced object is deleted, also delete the objects that have references to it (When you remove a blog post for
  instance, you might want to delete comments as well). SQL equivalent:
  CASCADE.
- **PROTECT**: Forbid the deletion of the referenced object. To delete it you will have to delete all objects that reference it manually.
  SQL equivalent: RESTRICT.
- **SET_NULL**: Set the reference to NULL (requires the field to be nullable). For instance, when you delete a User, you might want to
  keep the comments he posted on blog posts, but say it was posted by
  an anonymous (or deleted) user. SQL equivalent: SET NULL.
- **SET_DEFAULT**: Set the default value. SQL equivalent: SET DEFAULT.
- **SET(...)**: Set a given value. This one is not part of the SQL standard and is entirely handled by Django.
- **DO_NOTHING**: Probably a very bad idea since this would create integrity issues in your database (referencing an object that
  actually doesn't exist). SQL equivalent: NO ACTION.

source : [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)

Comment: I know about this parameter, but I don't have control over all model definitions. So I need to override the behaviour to always be DO_NOTHING (or PROTECT).